# VHDL: How to only update register at rising edge of the clock?

Tags: vhdl, clock, counter, process

I have a counter called lastelem_reg. At the rising edge of each clock, it should check whether another signal enqueue is HIGH. If it is, then lastelem_reg will be incremented by 1 in the next clock, otherwise it continues to hold its old value. This seems like a very simple problem, but I'm not getting the intended behavior. Here's the VHDL code:

```
    process(clk,reset)
    begin
        if (reset='1') then
            lastelem_reg    <= (others=>'0');
        elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
            lastelem_reg    <= lastelem_next;
        end if;
    end process;
    
    
    process(lastelem_reg)
    begin
        if (enqueue = '1') then
            lastelem_next <= lastelem_reg + 1;
        else
            lastelem_next <= lastelem_reg;
        end if;
    
    end process;
```

Simulating the above code, results in the waveform shown below. We see that lastelem_reg never gets updated.
[image]

So, I thought let's add enqueue to the sensitivity list of the second process and see what we get. The waveform is shown below. We see two things happening here that not supposed to happen. First, the lastelem_next signal changes twice every clock cycle, which shouldn't be happening. Second, the lastelem_reg is updating 1 clock before it should. For example, at 10ns, when the first enqueue signal comes, lastelem_reg should be 0, but here it is 1.

Any idea how to overcome this issue ?
[image]

Comment: There's nothing to overcome. Putting `enqueue` in the second sensitivity list is correct. There's nothing wrong with `lastelem_next` changing like that, and `lastelem_reg` is updating on every clock, because `enqueue` is asserted on every clock.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I could probably live with fact that lastelem_next is changing twice every clock cycle, but this leads to incorrect behavior as lastelem_reg is expected to start counting from 0. As you see, it starts counting from 1 here. This is because it is reacting to changes in enqueue before the clock comes, which is not correct behavior.

Comment: It IS starting at zero -- that's the value it has right up to the first clock edge. And `enqueue` is high at that clock edge, so it increments. If you want something different, you need to drive the inputs differently. Or if you want it to increment TO zero, then you need to reset it to all-ones (effectively -1).

Comment: By starting at 0, I meant that lastelem_reg should be 0 during the first clock pulse (with enqueue HIGH). It is only in the second clock that it should update to 1. But as you can see, lastelem_reg starts at 1 from the get go. This is problematic for me because I have a bunch of other modules that work based on the fact that lastelem_reg is 0 during the first clock (with enqueue HIGH). If I can overcome the issue here, then I wouldn't have to modify the other codes to adapt to this new behavior.

Comment: Then like I said before, reset `lastelem_reg` to all ones (`... (others => '1')`). Then the first `enqueue` operation will increment it to zero. On the other hand, if you don't want it to increment at all on that first clock edge, you must not assert `enqueue` there.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I appreciate it. Setting lastelem_reg to all 1 seems to be a good workaround. I'm relatively new to digital design, so I'm still quite nervous when it comes to ignoring things that are not behaving as expected. In your opinion, what are the downsides of lastelem_next changing twice in a clock cycle ? If there's one thing I've learn in digital design, it's that you can't just glue together a solution and get away with it. You absolutely need to know precisely what is going on every clock cycle or you end up with catastrophe down the road.

Comment: @ChadWinters I completely agree with your comment about knowing precisely what is inferred and/or happens with every single line you write. One thing that comes to mind is about unexpected/misleading simulations. You brought this to mind when you wrote about leaving out or including *enqueue* from your sensitivity list. I don't think it should affect the synthesis. But I've seen cases where it definitely impacts simulation in ways I couldn't fathom at the time. Can you try both ways and see if there is any difference in the synthesis (we already know there's a difference in simulation.)

Comment: @jonk I'll try synthesizing it when I'm done. The sad part about digital design is you simulate your circuit and it looking fine gives you no confidence. For instance, I was doing a mixed signal project where I had to design the control circuit for a DAC, which is working as a function generator. I simulated the circuit in ModelSim and it seems perfect. I synthesized it and simulated the gate-level netlist. The result was completely different from earlier. After an hour of searching, it turns out I forgot to include a default value for a signal and ModelSim didn't even tell me.

Comment: @ChadWinters Nothing to do with your problem, but directly having to do with your thoughts about needing to know exactly what is "going on" when you write code -- do you know ***exactly*** how the rising_edge() function expands out? You should. It should be burned into memory. (Um. Your memory. Not some RAM somewhere. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Forget using combinational processes with complicated and error-prone sensitivity lists, until the once-in-a-blue-moon time you actually need them.

Especially when you move on to state machines; but even here, a single synchronous process is cleaner and shorter, as well as much easier to get right. This reproduces the code you have (with the correction to the sensitivity list)

```
process(clk,reset)
begin
    if reset='1' then
        lastelement     <= (others=>'0');
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        if enqueue = '1' then
            lastelement <= lastelement + 1;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

There is one additional wrinkle in your problem specification however:

> At the rising edge of each clock, it should check whether another
> signal enqueue is HIGH. If it is, then lastelem_reg will be incremented by 1 **in the next clock**, otherwise it continues to hold its old value.

This needs an additional single cycle delay:

```
process(clk,reset)
begin
    if reset='1' then
        lastelement     <= (others=>'0');
        lastelement_d1  <= (others=>'0');
    elsif rising_edge(clk) then
        if enqueue = '1' then
            lastelement <= lastelement + 1;
        end if;
        lastelement_d1  <= lastelement;
    end if;
end process;
```

and I think lastelement_d1 (lastelement delayed 1 cycle) is what you are looking for.